# Pig Dump command throwing error

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Unable to fetch data form join.

**Data:**
Jorge Posada |Yankees| {(Catcher,2000),(Designated_hitter,2001)}|[games#1594,hit_by_pitch#65,grand_slams#7]
Landon Powell |Oakland|{(Catcher,2000),(First_baseman,2001)}|[on_base_percentage#0.297,games#26,home_runs#7]
Martin Prado |Atlanta| {(Second_baseman,2002),(Infielder,2003),(Left_fielder,2001)}|[games#258,hit_by_pitch#3]

```
**Code:**
bfile= LOAD 'basketball1.txt' using PigStorage('|') as (name:chararray,team:chararray,pos:bag{t:tuple(point:chararray,year:int)},bat:map[]);
bfile1= foreach bfile generate name,pos.year as year;
bfile2= foreach bfile1 generate name,flatten(year) as play_year ;
bfile3= group bfile2 by play_year;
bfile4= foreach bfile3 generate group,COUNT($1) as count;
bfile5= foreach bfile generate flatten(pos.year) as year,bat#'games' as games_cnt;
bfile6= group bfile5 by year;
bjoin= join bfile3 by group ,bfile6 by group;
bjoin1= foreach bjoin generate bfile3.group,bfile3::bfile2.name as name,
bfile6::bfile5.games_cnt as tot_games;
**Describe bjoin1:**
bjoin: {bfile3::group: int,bfile3::bfile2: {(name: chararray,play_year: int)},
bfile6::group: int,bfile6::bfile5: {(year: int,games_cnt: bytearray)}}
```

While doing **dump bjoin1** I face the following issue:

```
2014-11-15 07:31:42,318 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Some jobs have failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2014-11-15 07:31:42,321 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias bjoin1
Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1416065344409.log
grunt> 2014-11-15 07:31:47,857 [communication thread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - reduce > reduce
```

Comment: what's the version of hadoop and pig?

Comment: [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ pig --version
Apache Pig version 0.12.0-cdh5.1.0 (rexported)
compiled Jul 12 2014, 08:41:27

Comment: hadoop version as well?

Comment: [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.3.0-cdh5.1.0
Subversion git://github.sf.cloudera.com/CDH/cdh.git -r 8e266e052e423af592871e2dfe09d54c03f6a0e8
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-07-12T13:49Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 7ec68264497939dee7ab5b91250cbd9
This command was run using /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.3.0-cdh5.1.0.jar

Comment: Why do you have basketball data with Jorge Posada in it?